# synchronization between two process in c

Tags: c

I am trying to send signals between two child in alternative way for 100 times.

Here is my snippet of code.

here is the link to the whole question:
[sending signal between two child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858311/sending-signal-between-two-child-process)

But i have synchronization issue in the loop.
where is the right position to put the sigsuspend()?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <ctype.h>


pid_t pid2;
struct sigaction act;

sigset_t mask,oldmask,temp;

void sighandler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *ptr)
{
    printf("Received signal %d\n", signum);
    printf("Signal originates from process %lu\n",
        (unsigned long)info->si_pid);
        pid2 = info->si_pid;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
int i,j,counter = 0,counter2 = 0;
sigemptyset(&mask);
sigemptyset(&temp);
//sigemptyset(&oldmask);
sigaddset(&mask,SIGUSR1);

//sigset_t mask;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = sighandler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

    if(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, NULL) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "sigaction failed: %s\n", strerror(errno));


    pid_t current, pidOther;

    current = getpid();
    pidOther = atol(argv[1]);




int k;

for(k = 0;k < 100;k++){

if(pidOther != 0){ // second child
  kill(pidOther,SIGUSR1);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&mask,&oldmask);
  counter++;
  printf("2nd child = %d sent signal to 1st child = %d    signal number = %d\n",getpid(),pidOther,counter);
  //sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&mask,&oldmask);
  sigsuspend(&temp);
}


if(pidOther == 0)  // fisrt child
{
   //pause();
   kill(pid2,SIGUSR1);
   sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK,&mask,&oldmask); // was blank
   counter++;
   printf("\nj=%d  1st child = %d sent signal to 2nd child = %d    signal counter = %d\n",j,getpid(),pid2,counter);
   printf("test1\n");
   sigsuspend(&temp);  // was pause() 

  }

}

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you calling `fork()` anywhere. Also taking the process ID of the second process is not the way your program should know about the child process. Here's a simple example of how to use fork.

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
    // executes only in child process..
    // do stuff related what you need to do in child process
}
else
{
    // executes only in parent process
    // pid variable contains the child process's PID.
    // do stuff related what you need to do in parent process
}

// runs in both parent and child.
```

Comment: here is the link to my main question. I am creating fork in the main program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858311/sending-signal-between-two-child-process

Comment: @HoseinZarifi:  Don't spread your code over mulitple questions -- just ask ONE question with a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first time the first child loops, `pid2` is 0, so it sends the signal to every process in the process group (including itself), which means it will start looping immediately, sending signals (just) back to itself...

Comment: i dont think pid2 is ever 0 in this code, it's the pid of the second child that is retrieved through signal handler and stored in pid2 global variable.

Comment: Its initialized to 0 on program startup.  The first time into the loop, there has never been a signal received, so the signal handler has not yet run.